# Go и полиморфизм

Tags: golang

Пример:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type A interface {
    Foo()
}

type B struct{}

func (b *B) Foo() {
    // do smth...
}

func foo(b []*B) []A {
    return b // cannot use b (type []*B) as type []A in return argument
}

func main() {
    b := make([]*B, 10)
    a := foo(b)
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

Интерфейсу A полностью удовлетворяет тип `*B`, тогда почему я не могу вернуть из функции `[]*B` как `[]A`, и даже явное приведение типов не спасает? Где мой полиморфизм?
И есть ли какой способ превратить `[]*B` в `[]A`, кроме

```
aa := make([]A, 0, len(b))
for _, v := range b {
    aa = append(aa, v)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказывается, Google уже сам [ответил](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/InterfaceSlice) на мой вопрос. 
И в таком случае получается, что без явного пересоздания массива нет возможности на лету преобразовать слайс какого-то определенного типа в слайс интерфейсов.